# can we use \ as a escape sequence in os.system() in python

Tags: python

my code is

```
File "./e1.py", line 4
    os.system("mysqld_safe -u root -proot -e 'update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD(%s) where User="root"'" %rootpassword)
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There is no backslash in that string...

Comment: \" try using this

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 0):

absolutely

in your case you would do

```
system("mysqld_safe -u root -proot -e 'update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD(%s) where User=\"root\"'" % rootpassword)
```

where the \" is treated as a part of the string rather than the string enclosing.